# How to automatically exit browser after youtube video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, youtube, bandwidth

Is it possible to exit the browser ( firefox) automatically after a video  has finished playing ? Through some extensions / scripts ?

I need this because I want to automate measuring of bandwidth used while a youtube video played in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript API of youtube:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

```
player.getPlayerState():Number
    Returns the state of the player. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5).
```

You can handle it by javascript and close page after finished.